# Recurring Application Error after disabling Windows Error Reporting service

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-error-reporting

I am running Windows 8.1 - 64 bit version.

I followed the instructions listed here
http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/disable-error-reporting-windows
to disable Windows Error Reporting Service through the Action Center
as it was slowing down my system every time Windows found something wrong.

I have even made sure that the Error Reporting Svc was disabled in Services
and set to 1 (disabled) in the registry.

Yet quite often I still get an App Error message which slows my computer down anyways and even shows up in task manager as Windows Error Reporting Service. How is this still running?

The image I provided shows the error message I get and proof of WER service 
being shut down in the Action Center, Services and the Registry:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2011/02/18/how-to-disable-the-pop-up-that-windows-shows-when-an-app-crashes/), stopping the service and disabling reports no longer remove the error dialog. If you want to get rid of that too, you need to navigate to this Registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting
```

There is a `DontShowUI` entry in there; setting it to `1` removes the pop-up. Note that this is a per-user, not per-machine, setting (hence `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`).

---

There's also a different setting that might be more relevant to these "hard errors." According to [this KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/124873), set `ErrorMode` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows` to `2` if you want to remove all hard error dialogs. That setting is per-machine, and so affects all users.

Comment: I did both of these. I will post again on the results. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in getting back. The solution above has completely solved the issue and I no longer get the application error message. Thank you!